# Can Mass be found based on Volume?

Tags: mass

I am trying to calculate the mass of an object given the volume of an object without knowing what it is made of.  Is there a formula to find out something like this considering the object is on Earth at sea level?

Comment: You'd need to know more.  It's density or how much water it displaces when it floats, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass depends on volume and **density**.

As density of lead is 11 times that of water, while air is $10^{-3}$ of water, it really makes a difference what it is made out of.

However, most things we experience are much closer to the density of water. Wood is 0.7 of water, while concrete only twice as dense. In practice it is possible to get a pretty good a rough estimate based on how dense you think it is compared to water.

See below for the density of various materials.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density#Densities

Answer (score -1):

no it's impossible with out some additional data

Comment: Well, it is an answer, actually, just not a very informative one.